# Silent Install of MSI

Tags: windows, installation, msi, deployment, silent

What is the command line to silently install an MSI file?

Comment: Not all MSIs will allow silent installation, I don't think.

Comment: Find a full list of Command Line options here: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988.aspx

Comment: @Eddie: all real MSI files can be installed in silent mode by design, but it is indeed possible for vendors to mess this up by putting non-standard constructs into the MSI (custom actions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Standard Installer Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(VS.85).aspx)

> **/quiet**

Quiet display option.

The installer runs an installation without displaying a user interface.

Examples:

```
msiexec /package Application.msi /quiet
msiexec /uninstall Application.msi /quiet
msiexec /update msipatch.msp /quiet
msiexec /uninstall msipatch.msp /package Application.msi / quiet
```

Note  The equivalent Windows Installer Command-Line Option is `/qn`.

> **msiexec**

run this command to find more information about the installation options.

Answer (score 6):

---

**UPDATE June 2018**: Although the tool shown below is no longer available for download, I found it via Wayback machine. I assume it is OK and legal to link to it, seeing as the tool was freeware. Updated links below.

<del>**UPDATE**: *This tool from Wise is regrettably not downloadable anymore*. I am not sure if it is OK to distribute it either. It seemed to be a free tool distributed as part of their main Wise Package Studio suite, but I don't think it is open source. I wish they would release it as an open source tool.</del>

The Wise packaging products have been discontinued due to a number of [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions,_Inc.).

---

You got some good answers here already, but I just want to add the "quick and easy" way : use the "<del>**[command line builder tool](http://www2.wise.com/sysadmin_resources_page.asp)**</del>" from Altiris (<del>[direct download](http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe)</del>).

**UPDATE June 2018**: [http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20140402194132/http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe) - **broken link resurrected from Wayback machine**. Seeing as the tool was freeware I assume that is legal. Please run the download by [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) for safety.

I am very experienced with msiexec.exe, but the command lines are so long that it is easy to make mistakes. I prefer to generate the complex ones and eliminate that error source.

N.B: hope posting download links to tools is ok! I am not affiliated with Altiris in any way. It's a free tool, it's easy to use and it works. 
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: are the links dead? (off: command line builder gui wizard, what an idea)

Comment: I am sad to say this great tool appears to no longer be available for download from Wise since the overall Wise product has been taken off market. I am considering rewriting a similar tool myself.

Comment: Resurrected the tool for download from Wayback machine. Assume this is legal since the tool was freeware.

Answer (score 4):

See the docs for "Unattended":
http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

In short, while there are ways to cause them to fail, these flags should work:

```
 msiexec /qb /i blah.msi REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also these:

```
/q , /qn  No UI.
/qb       Basic UI.
/qb!      Basic UI with no cancel button.
/qr       Reduced UI. A modal dialog box is displayed at the end of the install.
/qf       Full UI. A modal dialog box is displayed at the end of the install.
/qn+      No UI. However, a modal dialog box is displayed at the end of the installation.
/qb+      Basic UI. A modal dialog box is displayed at the end of the installation. If you         cancel the installation, a modal dialog box is not displayed.
/qb-      Basic UI with no modal dialog boxes.
```

source: http://www.ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html